# Importing a mysql database with command line

Tags: mysql, linux, database, command-line, phpmyadmin

Have tried all other answers on stackoverflow, and they haven't worked. I have a database in phpMyAdmin, and I need to update it. The file is too big to upload via phpMyAdmin, and I've tried increasing limits in php.ini to no avail. I think that didn't work because I updated php.ini in public_html, and phpMyAdmin gets it memory/upload limits from the global file.

Anyhow, people recommend command line, so this is what I tried:

```
# mysql -u db_username -p db_pw -h localhost  existing_empty_db_name < new_db.sql
```

Then it just gives me a huge list of mysql options, and does nothing else. I refresh the db in phpMyAdmin, and nothing has changed.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `-D` option here. Correct syntax would be:

```
mysql -u db_username -p db_pw -h localhost -D existing_empty_db_name < new_db.sql
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now getting "Access denied for user 'db_username'@'localhost'.  Should I be entering the password for the server, or for the db?

Comment: @JaydenLawson Well, then you need to provide proper permissions to this user, or use another user. You can modify permissions using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks @shivams! No one in previous stackoverflow answers had explained that the username/password was for the account being used to log in to the server. I assumed that it was the username and password of the database!  Because I logged in as root, this command worked perfectly:

mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D existing_empty_db_name < new_db.sql

Note that I had to drop all tables in that database before it would successfully import.  Thanks so much!!